# Lattice points on the boundary of an ellipse

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, geometry, discrete-geometry, sums-of-squares

How many points of the integer lattice ${\mathbb Z}^2$ can an axis-parallel ellipse of radius $r$ contain on its boundary? (that is, we consider ${\mathbb Z}^2$ as lying in ${\mathbb R}^2$). Alternatively, this appears to be very similar to the question of how many points can the boundary of any axis-parallel ellipse contain from an $r\times r$ section of the integer lattice.

Let us say that the ellipse is defined as $(ax-b)^2+(cy-d)^2=r^2$. If $a,b,c,d$ are integers, we can reduce the problem to asking for the number of integer solutions to of an equation of the form $ax^2+by^2=r^2$ with integers $a,b$. This is known to have at most $r^{\frac{c}{\lg \lg r}}$ solutions, for some constant $c$. Does a similar bound exist for every axis-parallel ellipse?

In case it helps, I mainly care about the case where $a,b,c,d$ are not much larger than $r$.

Comment: Perhaps this might help? Cilleruelo, Javier, and Antonio Cordoba. "Lattice points on ellipses." *Duke Mathematical Journal* 76.3 (1994): 741-750. [*PDF download of preliminary version*](http://www.icmat.es/miembros/acordoba/documentos/articulos/Latticepointsonellipses.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Joseph. It is an interesting result, but unfortunately they consider only ellipses with a center at the origin. Non-integer centers seem to me as the main difficulty here.

Comment: Can you link or sketch the proof of $r^{c/\log\log r}$?

Comment: Sure. See for example Equation (11.9) in Section 11.2 of "Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms" by Iwaniec. By this formula the number of solutions to $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=r$ (under several additional conditions) is $\sum_{d|r}\left(\frac{b^2-4ac}{d}\right)$ times a small constant. The number of divisors or $r$ is at most $r^{c/\lg\lg r}$ and this is obviously an upper bound for above sum.

Answer (score 3):

For general ellipses I doubt you can do much better than Bombieri-Pila sort of bounds:

```
MR1016893 (90j:11099) Reviewed 
Bombieri, E.; Pila, J.
The number of integral points on arcs and ovals. 
Duke Math. J. 59 (1989), no. 2, 337–357. 
11P21 (11D99)
```

(you should check out the many papers that cite this, as well, but most of them seem to be interested in higher degrees/dimensions).

For integer coefficients, the best seems to be

Lattice points on Ellipses
Cilleruelo and Cordoba, DMJ 1994